# Raspberry Pi and Google Voice client type

Tags: raspberry-pi

I try to execute this code but it results in the following error.

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id inner-bonus-190416 --device-model-id inner-bonus-190416

INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com

WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Could not create the device instance. Client type need to be specified as SDK_LIBRARY or SDK_SERVICE.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what your problem is after reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i type in (env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id inner-bonus-190416 --device-model-id inner-bonus-190416
But then i get an erro

Comment: please edit your question explaining what you do, what your environment is and consider using the tools like ```this is some code``` to make code readable.

Comment: After editing your question I can tell you that the configuration file at ```/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json``` is missing. The error itself tells you that you need to add another argument or maybe configure it in the config if it's an ```SDK_LIBRARY``` or a ```SDK_SERVICE```

Comment: This is the error: Could not create the device instance. Client type need to be specified as SDK_LIBRARY or SDK_SERVICE.",

Comment: but if the error: "message": "Could not create the device instance. Client type need to be specified as SDK_LIBRARY or SDK_SERVICE.", was fixed then it would create the device_config.json i think

Comment: do you kow how to fix yet