# Embed the Google assistant in a Windows computer - device instance ID not generated while running the sample code

Tags: python, sdk, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, device-instance-id

I am trying to get Google Assistant installed on a Windows computer, following the instructions from *[Set Up Hardware and Network Access](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/setup?hardware=other)* (Google Assistant SDK).

I have been able to complete all but the last step. I am at the point of running the sample code. [https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/run-sample?refresh=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vach.jpg).

In this last step a 'device instance ID' should be generated, but that does not happen. See the screenshot:

[image]

The error message states that the client type needs to be specified as SDK_LIBRARY or SDK_SERVICE. However, when registering the model the '--client-type [SERVICE|LIBRARY]' option is not allowed (see *[Registration Tool Help](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/device-tool)*).

How can I run the sample code ... so that it generates a 'device instance ID'?

My problem seems to be similar to an issue reported by another user. This user reported the issue however for the Raspberry Pi, while I am reporting it for a Windows computer. See *[Raspberry Pi and Google Voice client type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170981/raspberry-pi-and-google-voice-client-type)*

Comment: solution: update the library, using the following command
py -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Apparently there was a bug in the library.
Updating the library solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder you downloaded the client secrets JSON file to, and paste in the following code:

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool --project-id PROJECT_ID register-model --model 'my-model-identifier' --type LIGHT --trait action.devices.traits.OnOff --manufacturer 'Assistant SDK developer' --product-name 'Assistant SDK light' --description 'Assistant SDK light device'
```

NB: Replace all details with the correct corresponding details.